Blender 4.3's Eevee fails to raytrace transmissive objects placed behind other transmissive objects
Just shifted from Blender 3.5 to Blender 4.3. Decided to test refractions. Jumped through a lot of hoops to enable basics refractions in Eevee. Unlike 3.5's Eevee, raytracing had to be compulsorily enabled, along with raytraced transmission within material settings (along with deferred rendering via dithered render method)
Refractions fail completely when render method is set to Blended for some strange reason, even though there were no issues in prior versions. That is not the main issue however
I made a very simple scene. Glass slab, monkey in front of it. Added a glass material, enabled relevant settings, could see the monkey through the glass
I decided to place another glass slab between the first glass slab and monkey and saw that it had 0 effect?
In fact, enabling raytraced transmission on the monkey completely makes it incapable of seeing through the glass at all, regardless of what material the monkey has


Link to my file: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/pcjp5vpx0wsk4wmhe0vvf/strangeGlass.blend?rlkey=c3hlwjxvxjyejyn2jz0hx0tyb&st=116lh9eq&dl=0

Render Method > Blended doesn't work with raytracing (you can hover this setting to get a description). I'm not sure I understand correctly the behavior you'd expect to get. Also, using https://blend-exchange.com/ would be great, so that we don't have to connect with a google account to download your file. Finally, we can't guess why devs make some choices over others. And keep in mind that raytracing with Eevee is a brand new feature : it may not support all features yet.

@Lutzi If I place two raytracing-transmission-enabled objects in front of each other (one red, and one blue for instance), and look from the red end, I would intuitively expect to see a purple translucent object (with refraction from the two objects of course)
However, I only see a red translucent object with refraction from just the red block. This doesn't seem to make sense?

@Lutzi I am assuming this might be due to some no of refraction bounces limit on eevee's end, but surely a limit of a single refraction has to be a bug and not an intended feature right?

As I said, I'll recommend you to go hover the setting, and you'll get your answer. It explains it. You either choose Dithered and can't have colored transparency, or Blended and can't have raytracing.

@Lutzi I am aware of that, in fact, that was how I'd noticed something was up. The problem isn't the lack of colored transparency, colored transparency more than works. It is that Dithered with raytracing doesn't allow you to trace refraction rays through more than one object at a time. I am aware that only Dithered works with raytracing, but surely only allowing a single refraction ray bounce per object is a bug right?

I really don't know :( hopefully someone used to Eevee can shade some light on that.
